# Swift what to return instead of nil?

Tags: swift, image, null

I know, that you can't return `nil` in Swift.
What could I use instead?

I have the following code:

```
public func getImageFromFilename(name: String) -> UIImage {
    print(name)
    var img: UIImage?
    img = UIImage(named: name + ".jpg")
    if (img == nil) {
        img = UIImage(named: name + ".png")
    }
    return img!
}
```

This code doesn't work if the file doesn't exists. What can I return to see if it was successful or not?
I want to return the image if it exists and otherwise I don't really know what to do.

Comment: Why not return a `UIImage?`

Comment: But how can I see if it was loaded successfully or not?

Comment: You can use Optional binding. I would really recommend you have a read of the [Optionals section](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330) of the language guide – it's quite a key concept in Swift.

Comment: Also this would probably be better served as a convenience initialiser for `UIImage`.

Answer (score 4):

There are two options.  You can either return `UIImage?` where `nil` as a returned result would indicate that loading of the file was not successful, or you return `UIImage` but make the method `throw` an error if the loading of the file fails.

Option with `UIImage?`

```
public func getImageFromFilename(name: String) -> UIImage? {
    print(name)

    if let img = UIImage(named: name + ".jpg") {
        return img
    }

    if let img = UIImage(named: name + ".png") {
        return img
    }

    return nil
}
```

Option with throwing:

```
public func getImageFromFilename(name: String) throws -> UIImage {
    print(name)

    if let img = UIImage(named: name + ".jpg") {
        return img
    }

    if let img = UIImage(named: name + ".png") {
        return img
    }

    throw YourErrorType.failedToLoadImage(name)
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I want to check in a `while loop` if the image is nil but I get an `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping optional value` error. I do it this way: `while (img == nil)`

Comment: why do you want to do that in while loop?

Comment: I do it as long as the image isn't nil so I can display it in an imageview?

Comment: I generate random number and if the file exists the while loop should stop and display it

Comment: that is a bit of an optimistic approach.  what if you are unlucky and random sequence that you get would be such that an image never exist?  ;)  why not predefine/scan-the-folder all possible images and then just pick the random one from those that certainly do exist?

Comment: I don't know how to do that